# Removing second colon

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Trying to create a simple script that lists mass mailing by the queue number that appears in /var/log/maillog. I'm starting off with this:

```
[root@ditirdlns01 ~]# lsMails(){ grep -i "$1-bounces@xxx.edu" /var/log/maillog | cut -f1-2,4 -d: ;}
[root@ditirdlns01 ~]#
```

Which yields:

```
[root@ditirdlns01 ~]# lsMails systems
Jul  1 15:12: AF649479A
Jul  1 15:14: 024682F59
Jul  1 15:14: 067A447B9
Jul  1 15:14: 0A3EA479A
Jul  1 15:14: 0DCBE5010
Jul  1 15:21: 97DAB2F59
Jul  1 15:24: D1D9B2F59
```

Which is perfectly alright except I want to get rid of the second colon (which in the log is what separates the minute from second, obviously. I actually don't want the second to be visible to users so cropping it out works for me). I tried piping it through sed looking for a colon preceded by a number with a space afterwards but I get identical results as before:

```
[root@ditirdlns01 ~]# lsMails(){ grep -i "$1-bounces@xxx.edu" /var/log/maillog | cut -f1-2,4 -d: | sed 's/([0-9]):\s+/ /g';}
[root@ditirdlns01 ~]# lsMails systems
Jul  1 15:12: AF649479A
Jul  1 15:14: 024682F59
Jul  1 15:14: 067A447B9
Jul  1 15:14: 0A3EA479A
Jul  1 15:14: 0DCBE5010
Jul  1 15:21: 97DAB2F59
Jul  1 15:24: D1D9B2F59
```

My specific question is: Why is `([0-9])` not matching a digit without including it in the result?

Comment: why don't you look for colon and space instead of number and colon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, [sed group capture](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regular-Expressions) requires that the parentheses be escaped. Also the `+` repetition character needs to be escaped.

If you replace the `sed` portion of your command pipeline with the following, it should work:

```
 sed 's/\([0-9]\):\s\+/\1 /g'
```

Comment: If you use `sed -E` then you don't need to escape the brackets (that isn't POSIX, though)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's/://2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you look for colon and space instead of number and colon

try this:

```
lsMails(){ grep -i "$1-bounces@xxx.edu" /var/log/maillog | cut -f1-2,4 -d: | sed 's/: / /g';}
```